# secure a raspberry pi so it can only run one application

Tags: touchscreen, security

Given that only a touch screen is accessible, how can I lock down a raspberry pi so that only one application (a calculator program) will run?

Comment: calmwm - impossible to exercise ‘run’ dialog without a keyboard, run a loop to keep the calculator alive forever

Answer (score 2):

Don't start programs you don't want your users to access (or uninstall these programs altogether). I'm pretty sure it's impossible to install or start a program using a typical calculator interface.